# Error using GotoIf in a dialplan

Tags: asterisk, telephony, goto

I am trying to implement a complex dialplan that requires interaction with the user. Based on this interaction, the dialplan jumps to another part. Some sample code is given below:

```
[test]
;This is a test.

exten => 0,n(qa1),NoOp()
exten => 0,1,Verbose(1, "This is a test")
exten => 0,n,Set(USER_ANSWER=0)
exten => 0,n,Read(USER_ANSWER,,1,,2,10)
exten => 0,n,Verbose(1, "User keyed in ${USER_ANSWER}")

exten => 0,n,GotoIf($[$["${USER_ANSWER}"="1"] | $["${USER_ANSWER}"="2"]]?eval1:qa1)
exten => 0,n,Verbose(1, "User keyed in ${USER_ANSWER}")

exten => 0,n(eval),NoOp()
...
```

1. On running the above code, asterisk hangs up after evaluating the `GotoIf` condition above. The error messages are as follows:

   -- User entered '1'
       -- Executing [0@test:19] Verbose("DAHDI/13-1", "1, "User keyed in 1"") in new stack
     "User keyed in 1"
       -- Executing [0@test:20] GotoIf("DAHDI/13-1", "1?eval1:qa1") in new stack
       -- Goto (test,0,21)
       -- Executing [0@test:21] NoOp("DAHDI/13-1", "") in new stack
   [Jan 25 10:47:48] WARNING[29738]: pbx.c:3677 pbx_extension_helper: No application 'If' for extension (test, 0, 22)

My questions are:

1. What does that error message mean?
2. How can I correct it so it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `GotoIf` is invoked correctly. The label `eval1` has `If` statements following it. Asterisk does not have `If` statements. Replacing the `If` statements with `ExecIf` did the trick. One can figure out what commands are available by typing, at the Asterisk CLI prompt, the following command:
`core show application <command name here>`
If the above command returns an output, then that command is available, else not.